# Django, page is rendering objects after id have been deleted

Tags: python, django, model

I stored and object id in session, and i am getting the id to query and render values of that model, after deleting the id from the session the values of that model still show in the template after page reload, how can i stop this? 
here is my code

````
def dashboard(request):
    customer_form = CustomerInfoForm()
    form = TransactionForm(initial={'tax':0,'price':0, 'price_per_item':0})

    if 'id' in request.session:
        id =  request.session['id']
        print('Id in dashboard is ', id)
        order = Order.objects.get(pk=id).item_set.all()
        sum_of_price = order.aggregate(Sum('price'))
        #Get sum of all item prices.
        if sum_of_price :
            context['price'] = sum_of_price['price__sum']
            context['current_order'] = Order.objects.get(pk=id).item_set.all()
    context['form'] = form
    context['customer_form'] = customer_form
    return render(request, 'main/dashboard.html', context)```

In the second view i am deleting the id and when i reload the page the first view still query and render values to the page, 

```@csrf_exempt
def add_order_as_credit(request):
    try:
        price = request.POST.get('price')
        id = request.session.get('id')
        order = Order.objects.get(pk=id)
        order.price = price
        order.save()
        print('Id is  ', request.session['id'])
        print('Price is ' + price)
        del request.session['id']
        return JsonResponse('Order has been set as credit', safe=False)
    except (KeyError, Order.DoesNotExist):
        return JsonResponse('There is no order ', safe=False)```
````

Answer (score 0):

In some instances, it's required to explicitly mark the session as modified:

```
del request.session['id']
request.session.modified = True
```

See [the Django docs on sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved).

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies where should i set that in the first or second view? Thanks

Comment: See my edit. Let me know and mark as correct if it works.

Comment: Its still renders objects after session has been deleted

Comment: Its only disappear if i restart the server

Comment: Hmm, could it be that id is too generic? Try `item_id` and let me know.  I also wonder whether you can alter session variables when you’re not returning `request` in the response.